# Burn the books of [learning]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I've come across [learning](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), which is only tagged with 15 questions right now.  It seems unneeded because it doesn't add anything important to the question.  We already have [beginner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner), which sort of already implies that the OP is currently learning.  If the OP were indeed posting some code for learning purposes, that could still be mentioned in the question (but very briefly).

I'm also not sure what will happen to [this poor old off-topic question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31/essential-reading-learning-resources-for-the-code-reviewer), which has this as its *only* tag...

Burninate?

[image]

Comment: I think it will be auto-tagged with the system [tag:untagged] tag.

Comment: @retailcoder: I did not know that that even existed. :-)

Comment: I know it's on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged

Comment: @retailcoder: Wow, look at those rejects.  Hopefully the mods here will find reason to finally use this tag.  This is the one question that doesn't need any other tags.

Comment: It should actually be migrated to Programmers.SE, as hinted in the comments (and even one of the answers!)

Comment: @retailcoder: Isn't there some policy about not migrating old question?  I agree that it shouldn't be here, but I'm wonder how those folks will take it.

Comment: Bah, you're right, let it be CR's first untagged question then :)

Comment: @retailcoder: Let's see what the mods think, then.  I love keeping this site clean, especially while it's still in beta.

Comment: Thank you, Shog!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seconded — the [learning](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) tag adds nothing of value.  We're all here to learn.  At least [beginner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) signals responders to keep the answer simple.

As for that one off-topic question, it's already closed, and could just be deleted.

Comment: I suppose that could happen.  Since a mod will need to delete to burninate this tag (if approved) and that question is already linked, its fate will be decided.  I'll put in my delete vote anyway.