# What's a Zombie? And what are the many other memes of Code Review?

Tags: discussion, fun

What is a Zombie? Why are Code Reviewers so violent and talking about killing Zombies all the time? And what ammo are they talking about? What is a TS? What does RSA mean?

And what other Code Review-specific memes are there?

(As the number of memes grows and grows, and Malachi's wish to vote for the memes more than once, this really ought to have its own meta-question)

Please provide only one, or just a few tightly-coupled, memes per answer.

Comment: Many memes are listed in [this answer to the Call of Duty topic](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1029/34757).

Comment: should _RELOAD!_ be on the list? I see it occurring frequently, from Duga's daily report of unanswered questions as well [as other regulars in the 2nd](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=reload&Room=8595&page=44&pagesize=50&sort=newest)...maybe it is a _Call of Duty_ phrase but I'm not familiar with the phrases in it...

Answer (score 70):

**Meme:** Zombies

**Originator:** Mathieu Guindon (aka retailcoder, lol.upvote, ... and/or Mat's Mug)

**Cultural Height:** During [The Mission](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999/call-of-duty-were-on-a-mission/)

**Background:** In a (successful) attempt to motivate the community in reducing the number of unanswered questions, a Call of Duty was made in which every unanswered question (no upvoted answers) is to be regarded as a Zombie. Every new question is to be regarded as an incoming Zombie.

Comment: [Tshirt anyone?](http://i.imgur.com/1IwREPv.jpg)

Comment: What is an "unanswered question"? A question with no answers? A question with no accepted answers? A question with answers that have no upvotes? I suppose it's the last one. It might be worth to clarify, or if already explained somewhere else, then include a link.

Comment: @janos I don't think there is an exact definition about that. The StackExchange system handles it differently in different places, but it's definitely not related to accepted answers.

Answer (score 64):

**Meme:** Jamalized

**Originator:** [Jamal ♦](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22222/jamal) (actually, apparently [me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=12312957#12312957))

**Cultural Height:** All over CR (see this [chat transcript search](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=jamalized&room=8595))

**Background:** Jamal being a [frantic editor](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all). And he's fast. So fast, we're all waiting for the day he will edit a bad question title before it's even posted. You never know, maybe mods will have the power to edit post *drafts* one day.

And he knows:

> *I don't even pay attention to dates. I just edit like Dr. House takes Vicodin.*
>   <sub>http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12505099#12505099</sub>

And so "Jamalized" was coined, vaguely meaning "edited". Applicable to any `IEditable<T>`.

Comment: I don't think this will count as a real meme until Jamal edits this post.

Comment: "we're all waiting for the day he will edit a bad question title before it's even posted" Maybe that's how good question titles exist *already*?

Comment: He might have run out of things to edit on Code Review, because he's also suggesting edits on  [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12588434).

Comment: Bearing in mind one likely doesn’t vocalize this term often, how should it sound when spoken? Initially in my head I presumed like _ja-mal-**ized**_, but was recently thinking it should perhaps be more like _ja-**mal**-ized_

Answer (score 43):

**Meme:** Java vs. JAVA

**Originator:** Jamal(?) (to be determined)

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) (as usual), but also in various comments scattered across meta.

**Background:** Question with the word JAVA (instead of Java) in the title or body, is often an indication that the poster is a beginner and/or [that it's a low-quality question](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14230402#14230402). This has led to the separation of JAVA from Java. They are now, at least among the regulars in The 2nd Monitor on Code Review, treated as two entirely different languages.

**Examples:**

> @skiwi Java? No, we're hiring JAVA people. Sorry.

([chat post](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=16280505#16280505))

> Just don't learn JAVA @Jamal.

([comment on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/let-the-cr-games-begin/2044#comment5281_2043))

> Never mind, I realised that you're talking about JAVA, which is not a language I know.

([@rolfl in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=16358847#16358847)) (@rolfl is among the top Java users here, but he does not know JAVA apparently)

Comment: Nice one! Who would have tough there were so many others bothered by quirky capitalization? :P

Comment: I really feel this meme… I see this on Stack Overflow all the time. Bonus points if it’s tagged [javascript].

Answer (score 38):

**Meme:** TS | RSA

**Originator:** SimonAndréForsberg (TS), rolfl (RSA)

**Cultural Height:** [star-power](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-power)

**Background:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) is quite a star-happy chatroom. How many of you know that there's only a number of times you can "star" a chat post - a **star cap** (like the *rep cap* and the *vote cap*, a *star cap*). And just when you run out of stars to sprinkle, someone posts a comment and you're dying to "star" it - no worries, you can put a *theoretical star* `TS`, and then it's possible someone applies a *real* one (`RSA`: "*real star applied*").

Answer (score 38):

**Meme:** "Thanks, Santa!"

**Originator:** [Jamal ♦](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22222/jamal)

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

**Background:** Votes are anonymous. So whenever someone upvotes a post of yours, and you think the voter might be in the chatroom, just say "**Thanks, Santa!**", the voter(s) will know that was for them.

Comment: I forget... did this meme come up *after* Christmas?

Comment: @Jamal that's something I'd have to dig up to make sure, but I *think* it *was* after the Holidays :)

Comment: You are welcome, though, I am a but miffed that I could not write this entry ;)

Comment: Don't the post votes only show up an hour after they are cast? (in order to prevent the voter from swapping/etc. and allow it to lock in)?

Comment: @user2813274 nope. You usually get pretty much instant notification that you've earned rep ;)  ...and lock-in is 5 minutes; on-page vote counts update in real-time, and vote counts on profile pages have a cache lag.

Answer (score 36):

**Meme:** Monking

**Originator:** [Morwenn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=14493260#14493260)

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

**Background:** A morning greeting to the [Monkey](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/) doing his [monkey-business](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monkey-business), in other words: [monking](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monking)

**Examples:** [A small chat search](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=monking&Room=8595&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest)

**Variations:** Monkernoon, Monkevening, Monknight, and the reversed [gniknoM](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=gniknoM&room=8595) sometimes used when one leaves... Important is only that it begins with Monk... ;)

Also sometimes known as [Nibjubg](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nibjubg&Room=8595&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest) in case your fingers are not where they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 33):

**Name:** Overly long acronyms

**Originator**: [Simon André Forsberg](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/98071/) with [this message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14497608#14497608)

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

**Background:** IWNPFETTOLAI (I will not provide further explanation than this overly long acronym itself)

Comment: Really, I started those? I'm blaming monkeys...

Comment: @Simon then prove it and edit ;)

Comment: @Vogel612 aha! He declines. Proof given.

Answer (score 27):

**Meme:** LOL - AutoStar

**Originator:** Mat's Mug / Jamal

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

**Background:** "lol" somehow got targeted at this point here (the first starred *lol*):

> *retailcoder*: [lol (darn, again)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12506489#12506489)

Followed shortly by:

> *Jamal*: [lol (don't star that)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12506860#12506860)

And then the tradition was cemented with:

> *Jamal*: [Why the heck would you star "lol"? sigh](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12506855#12506855)

Answer (score 25):

**Meme:** [TTQW | TTGH] | TTGTB

**Originator:** [attributed to] [Simon André Forsberg](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/98071/) ([first TTQW here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14099197#14099197))

**Cultural Height:** [The](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=TTQW&Room=8595&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest) [2nd](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=TTGH&user=&room=8595) [Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=TTGTB&user=&room=8595)

**Background:** leaving the chatroom and/or going AFK isn't something we do often. These funky acronyms efficiently communicate that it's either *time to quit work* (or *time to get home*), or *time to go to bed*.

Related: [stack-and-drive](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-and-drive) (don't do that!)

Answer (score 25):

**Meme:** Yet another [linked-list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-list) (also [nooooooooo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nooooooooo))

**Originator:** [skiwi](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/110433/skiwi)

**Cultural Height:** The apparent popularity of linked list implementations

**Background:** The site has received [a lot of linked list questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-list) with more coming in over time.  It has also led to many duplicate titles and even some duplicate information in answers.  Some users even (jokingly?) posted linked list implementations on April Fools Day for review (or just for teh lulz).  This was [proposed in CR on April 1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14590911#14590911) by skiwi

**Other forms:** Yet another [fizz-buzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fizz-buzz)

Comment: -1 just because it's related to Linked-Lists (Also related to: [tag:nooooooooooo])

Answer (score 22):

**Meme:** Exploding bear traps

**Originator:** [Grace Note](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5999)

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor), Website Graduation

**Background:** During the endless talk about Code Review graduation, some were wondering whether Code Review could even graduate some day or was doomed and would close. [The answer was as follows](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=14014437#14014437):

> There really isn't an axe over your heads even now. You'd have to, like, torch everyone on the site and then set exploding bear traps for new visitors in order to drop things low enough to get you guys in any sort of danger zone.

**Examples:**

> *ChrisW:* exploding bear traps would reduce the number of new users ...

Also:

> *Mat's Mug:* note: torching everyone on the site wouldn't be enough. We'd have to also set exploding bear traps for new visitors!

Or even:

> *rolfl:* That immature side of me really feels that some of the new questions deserve exploding bear-traps...

---

> *Simon André Forsberg:* @rolfl when in doubt, use exploding bear traps?[<sub>link</sub>](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14625459#14625459)

Generally speaking, *torching everyone on the site* is less used but has the same meaning. But that does not sound half as fun as *exploding bear traps*.

Comment: Lest it be misunderstood, my using "exploding bear traps" in that context was meant to be a "reductio ad absurdum": to cast doubt on the usefulness of a metric which (it seems to me) will penalize a site for having a continuous influx of new users; and not to suggest that new users are unwelcome.

Answer (score 22):

**Meme:** Smoking The Documentation / STM

**Originator**: [Simon](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15880296#15880296), in response to a question by [rolfl](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15880186#15880186)

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

**Background:** "The documentation." is now a common response to rhetorical question like "What was I smoking when I wrote this?". This is often followed by "STM again?" (Smoking the manual again?).

Answer (score 21):

**Meme:** Pimping my answer

**Originator:** [rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl)

**Cultural Height:** Lack of voting on answers

**Background:** In an effort to increase exposure to under-voted answers, users on The 2nd Monitor started ["pimping their answers" for more attention](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Pimp&Room=8595&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest).  It can be used for your own answer, answers from others, or even entire questions with good answers.

During the mission this was also referred to as: "killcam"

Answer (score 20):

> This meme has been retired by [community decision](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3780/42632) on Nov 25 2014. It is thus considered a veteran meme. Usages may still occur, but the meme has largely vanished from our site.

**Meme:** *We could really use your ammo*

**Originator:** syb0rg

**Cultural Height:** Side-effects of [The Mission](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999/call-of-duty-were-on-a-mission/)?

**Related:** [out-of-ammo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/out-of-ammo) and `DVLR` (*daily vote limit reached*)

**Background:** Activity on CR has recently taken a hell of a spike. 40 votes/day isn't enough ammunition to shoot at all the good answers that are thrown at all incoming zombies. Increased activity is awesome.

But basically:

## We need your <s>soul</s> *votes*!

It's a matter of life vs death. *We could really use your ammo* is serious business.

---

The bottom line is: ***we** (**you** & us all) **own this site***. Let's give it the lovin' it deserves, and make it run on a healthy economy of votes and reputation points, with people putting bounties on good <s>unanswered questions</s> *zombies*  they stumble upon, people coming here on meta and asking questions about the site, where CR is, where it's headed and where it should be. ***Be* Code Review!**.

Answer (score 18):

**Name:** [wtf-is-this-shit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wtf-is-this-shit)

**Originator:** [Jamal](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=wtf-is-this-shit&Room=8595&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest)

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

**Background:** Often used to point out that, even though some code technically works, it is *so bad* that it deserves a weapons-grade facepalm. It can also be used to describe a "feature" of a language or program that's just a PITA.

It was popularized by Jamal, skiwi, Mat'sMug, ckuhn203 and yours truly. Its origin is linked to the JAVA meme.

> Jamal: @Mat'sMug brb synonymizing [JAVA] and [wtf-is-this-shit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wtf-is-this-shit) - Jun 30 8:35 PM

Comment: A *"weapons-grade facepalm"*? Is that like a nuke to the face or something?

Comment: Basically yes :)

Answer (score 18):

**Meme:** hello / hi / hey there

**Originator:** Code Reviewers

**Cultural height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

**Background:** Code Reviewers like to greet each other in chat, and most of the time it's just a casual "Hello" then "Hi @someone". But on days of high activity, some unusual things can happen...

[image: heythere]

Or...

[image: hello]

Or even...

[image: hi]

Comment: This is not only restricted to the 2nd monitor... in the tavern this is called 'trains' and it happens with.. lots of words

Answer (score 17):

> This meme has been retired by [community decision](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3780/42632) on Nov 25 2014. It is thus considered a veteran meme. Usages may still occur, but the meme has largely vanished from our site.

**Meme:** [napalmd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/napalmd)

**Originator:** [Mat's Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug) (/retailcoder /lol.upvote)

**Cultural Height:** During [The Mission](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999/call-of-duty-were-on-a-mission/)

**Background:** War against zombies sometimes needs more than a single bullet. When CR forces unite to take down a zombie with multiple answers, the term [napalmd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/napalmd) indicates, in The 2nd Monitor, that all answers (and the question) have been upvoted.

Of course that only happens when *all answers* deserve a vote!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16763/discussion-between-rolfl-and-sampablokuper).

Answer (score 17):

**Meme:** JDQ

**Originator:** [rolfl](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=13521993#13521993)

**Cultural Height:** The 2nd Monitor

**Background:** [JavaDeveloper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/28539/javadeveloper) is one of the users who has posted the most questions on Code Review<sup>[1](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/edit/1368947)</sup>. A JDQ is of course, a JavaDeveloper Question. JavaDeveloper is the first one, and currently the only one, who have received the newly invented [Socratic **golden badge**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/134/socratic).

According to a [rough SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/206315/reputation-from-a-users-posts), at least a total of 9540 reputation has been created on the site thanks to answers to the questions posted by JavaDeveloper.

Comment: At this moment @Mat'sMug is the second one who received the badge

Answer (score 17):

**Meme:** For some values of X

**Originator:** Probably [Phrancis](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=21731372#21731372)

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

**Background:** It all seems to have started with this message by Phrancis:

> I'm a web dev, for some values of web dev. Not many.

Followed 2 days later by Mat's Mug's:

> well that works.. for some values of "works"

In the [VBA Rubberducking](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking) room, followed by a rather explosive usage around the election time, see also the [chat search](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=for%20some%20values%20of&Room=8595&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest)

Answer (score 16):

**Meme:** [phpoop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phpoop)

**Originator:** Mat's Mug

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

**Background:** [php](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) is [frequently used](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/php/info) (see "related tags") along with [oop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oop). The contraction of the two gave birth to [phpoop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phpoop)... only in the chatroom (don't you *dare* actually create that tag!).

Related: [phpoop-security](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phpoop-security)

Answer (score 15):

**Meme:** Friday

**Originators:** [rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503), [SimonForsberg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-forsberg) & [Jamal](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22222/jamal)

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

**Background:** On Jan 10 2014, the following remark was made in the chat room:

> Simon André Forsberg: It's Friday, Friday. Gotta write code on Friday. *singing*

And then this happened:

[image: omg]

Since then, it has been customary for Simon to tease on Friday:

> hey @Malachi... you know what day it is?

Shortly followed by the YouTube video, and shortly afterwards by **OMG**, [nooooooooo](http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/) or [noooooo](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noooooo) or even *"You monster."* from others present in the chat room.

---

Since this meme has begun, some users in the 2nd Monitor have rebelled and begun posting [this The Cure video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wa2nLEhUcZ0) instead.

Comment: According to Mat's Mug Friday is the time to refactor every thing and push to production by 5PM.

Answer (score 15):

**Meme:** German Overengineering™

**Originator**: Vogel612

**Cultural Height:** [Various questions, answers, and chat messages involving @Vogel612](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=german%20overengineering&Room=8595&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest)

**Background:**

Programmers like to abstract and engineer things. Sometimes, it just becomes too much.

*German Overengineering™* is exactly what it sounds like, a case of when something has become overly-engineered.

Comment: Variations may include Dutch and Swedish overengineering

Answer (score 14):

**Meme:** @CaptainObvious (the bot formerly known as @StackExchange)

**Originator:** Unknown/CR chat community

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

**Background:** @CaptainObvious is the ever-vigilant bot/feed of Code Review, faithfully posting new questions, good and bad, to The 2nd Monitor. It is often interjected @CaptainObvious with a comment about the latest question, such as...

> Jamal
>   May 5 6:44 PM |
>   @CaptainObvious Could use a better title. This one is kinda useless.
>
> rolfl
>   May 1 3:16 PM |
>   @CaptainObvious Code is obviously broke, Captain Obvious.
>
> skiwi
>   May 1 8:37 PM |
>   @CaptainObvious Strange... replacing a standard utility with his/her own invented implementation and then complaining that the performance is too low.
>
> Simon André Forsberg
>   May 4 4:54 PM | 
>   @CaptainObvious Holy mother of over-engineering!
>
> Phrancis
>   Aug 1 6:59 PM |
>   @CaptainObvious *Optimizing the title of my question*
>
> RubberDuck
>   Jul 28 4:45 AM |
>   lol. Looks like it. Poor @CaptainObvious must get lonely when we're not around.

@CaptainObvious has even been witnessed, some say, to drop by and say `Hi!` on rare occasions...

[image: Hi]

Answer (score 13):

**Meme:** Stargree, Stargreed

**Originator:** [Skiwi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/32231/skiwi)

**Cultural Height:** [A conversation about a duck](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/conversation/stargreed)

**Background:** Stars shine in CR chat quite fluently, and it sort of means that we either find it funny or that we agree, if this were Facebook they would be Likes

Comment: Quack!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 12):

**Meme:** Malachi'd

**Originator:** [Malachi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/18427/malachi)

**Cultural Height:** Whenever there is something that is amusing or entertaining and it hasn't been starred yet.

**Background:** Starring everything that is amusing or entertaining.

---

***Alternate Meaning:*** Randomly posting a picture or video in chat to break up the monotony of the daily grind at work.

Answer (score 10):

**Meme:** BTW

**Originator**: [attributed to]  [Malachi, Mat's Mug and Others](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14393815#14393815)

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

**Background:** The many ways of backronymizing btw led to the introduction of the BTW enum:

```
public enum BTW{
   Bananas,
   Bring,
   Normal,
   Waffles,
   Wall,
   Web,
   Win,
   Woods,
   Work 
}
```

<sub>This list does not claim completeness. New interpretations may happen any time</sub>

Also somewhat related: [TTQW](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1643/37660)

Comment: Bananas To Work, Bring To Work, Behind The Wall

Comment: Back To Work not Bring To Work....*ugh*

Answer (score 10):

**Meme:** HOLY CARP

**Originator**: [Malachi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/18427/malachi)

**Cultural height:** Mostly [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

**Background:** Dec 2013

It may or may not have been a typo, but [as recorded in The 2nd Monitor originally](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=holy%20carp&Room=8595&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest):

> Malachi Dec 11 '13 11:10 PM
>   105.1k close votes needed on Stackoverflow. holy carp

It has since been used fairly frequently, often in **SHOUT CASE**, to express surprise or astonishment.

PS: It is also occasionally accompanied by other references to fish like "mackerel" and such.

Comment: For the record, "Holy mackerel" is a phrase I've heard in the real world.

Comment: And Holy Halibut

Answer (score 10):

**Meme:** Using puns in the titles of [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) questions on Meta.

**Originator:** [@Jamal](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/877/burn-the-books-of-learning)

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) & Meta

**Background:** Meta is often a serious<s>*ly fun*</s> place, so any kind of humorous jokes we can slip in here and there go a long way.

> @Simon: [A burninate-request without a pun? How is that even possible?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22537099#22537099)

**Examples:**

> [I don't think this tag [functions] quite well](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5566/i-dont-think-this-tag-functions-quite-well)
>
> [Do we need this [crud]?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5516/do-we-need-this-crud)
>
> [Dispose of [idisposable]?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5595/dispose-of-idisposable)
>
> [Is [methodology]'s methodology worthy of burnination?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/is-methodologys-methodology-worthy-of-burnination)
>
> [set [null] = null? (or "Burninate [null]?")](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/set-null-null-or-burninate-null)
>
> [action = ([ternary-operator] == bad_tag ? "burninate" : "keep")](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5630/tag-ternary-operator-burninate-if-bad-else-keep)

Comment: this goes waaaayy back to the early days of MSO.. people making punny titles for burninate requests is as old as burninate-requests

Answer (score 7):

> This meme has been retired by both community decision and [Simon's decision](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25112627#25112627) on the **1/11/2015**. It is thus considered a veteran meme. Usages may still occur, but the meme has largely vanished from our site.

**Meme**: "INTERRUPT"

**Originator**: [Possibly @EthanBierlein](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=22128093#22128093)

**Cultural Height**: [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

**Background**:

Whenever Duga posts the message:

> ***RELOAD!***

in chat, a user might say:

> ***INTERRUPT!***

---

[Why?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23270294#23270294)

> @Mat'sMug: it's a [race-duga-to-chat](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/race-duga-to-chat) thing

Comment: Retired, as @Duga now posts only one message at ***RELOAD*** time.  Retired as of November 2, 2015.

Answer (score 6):

**Meme:** `s/old message/new message/`

**Originator:** Unknown

**Cultural Height:** [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

**Background:**

Often in chat, a user will type something like this:

```
s/funny/annoying/
```

In response to what another user said as a "joke edit". Occasionally it is actually used to correct spelling.

The meme comes from [GNU's SED](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command).

Comment: For the record, it's also used in other chatrooms.

Answer (score 5):

**Meme:** Here Be Pedants

**Originator:** [Mat's Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug)

**Cultural Height:** The 2nd Monitor, Meta

**Background:** Originally introduced by [Mat's Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug) in an [answer on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/37660),
 it got quickly adapted [into chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=pedants&Room=8595&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest) by [Dan Pantry](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42325/dan-pantry), [Zak](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/81541/zak), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast) and possibly other regulars where it mutated from a proud declaration "Don't get me wrong, a lot of Code Review regulars are complete pedants. We love being pedantic" into a warning, leaning on "Here Be Dragons"

**Beware: Here Be Pedants**

Answer (score 5):

**Meme:** Skiwi (verb), e.g. "skiwi'd"

**Originator:** [IvenBach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/131748/ivenbach) (?)

**Cultural Height:** [VBA Rubberducking](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking)

**Background:** [Skiwi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/32231/skiwi) has long been renowned to consistently have well over 1000 open tabs in his browser. "To skiwi something" means to open a browser tab and leave it opened to get back to it... eventually.

[image: Skiwi's browser tabs]

Answer (score 4):

**Meme:** Floating Point Police™

**Originator:** [JS1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/102155/27975)

**Cultural Height:** ???

**Background:**

> As a proud member of the Floating Point Police™, I'm issuing you citation for unnecessary use of floating point here.

(*[Source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/102155/27975)*)

Answer (score 4):

**Meme**: [fizzbuzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz)

**Originator**: ??? (Probably Mat'sMug, or maybe indirectly Jeff Atwood's blog post)

**Cultural Height**: Current

**Background**: It's famously been said that a language cannot be considered a proper language on Code Review until someone has written a FizzBuzz for that language.

> [Example 1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27492525#27492525) and [Example 2](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26263645#26263645)

Answer (score 0):

**Meme**: panny

**Originator**: [Der Kommissar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/154925/der-kommissar)

**Cultural Height**: The 2nd Monitor

**Background**:

> Der Kommissar: *Working, learning piano, and fixing my house. Been keeping busy with the panny.*

> Mast: *Psychological Association of Northeastern New York?*

> Der Kommissar: *@Mast Colloquial term for "COVID pandemic", something my girlfriend says lol*

([Source 1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=57573845#57573845))