# Should we kill Santa?

Tags: discussion, voting

[Santa](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1526/23788) is frequently found in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor). Santa can do magic, and sprinkle upvotes to all the boys and girls that have been good reviewers this year.

Santa generates quite a bunch of reputation points on the site, we like Santa.

However Santa is fraying with a thin line between legit and suspicious voting schemes prone to *vote reversal*, and can earn a user 20, 30, 40, or even 50 points by browsing *a user's recent answers* and finding well-written answers that weren't already upvoted.

I've worn Santa's hat quite often myself, and then a recent comment in chat that linked to the [weekly user reputation rankings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week) made me wonder.

---

We have many users (>40K), but ~25% (10,653, avg.score 149.16) have visited the site in the last 60 days, 14.78% (1,574, avg.score 602.24) of which were *avid users* (>150pts).

Roughly 9,5K *answer votes* and 7.2K *question votes* (16,673 votes) were spent in that timeframe, by roughly 150-160 voters, generating roughly 130,000 points on the site. **Santa's actual impact on the big picture is marginal**, it's like a drop in the ocean. Or is it? It *does* seem to somewhat skew some rankings.

#### But that leaves over 1,300 (83%) avid users that didn't vote, and 10,500 (**a whopping 98.6%**) active users that haven't spent a vote either.

If only **a fraction** of these users spent some of their votes, whether Santa exists or not wouldn't make a difference. But...

## [♠] People. Still. Don't. Vote. Enough. [♠]

---

So. Should we kill Santa? [Is Santa being a good thing for CR](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=santa&room=8595)?

Comment: Nooooo ..... Santa lives!

Comment: Give him coal, Santa!  Give him *all teh coalz*!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## No... Santa lives.

The question is not whether Santa is a bad thing. The question is:

### Everyone should be Santa, why are they not?

**How can we get the other 98.6% of users to be Santa too?**

---

---

Everyone can be Santa, if you <kbd>VOTE!</kbd>

- If you see a question, and you think:

  > well presented, hmmm, interesting...

  then <kbd>VOTE!</kbd> (up)
- If you see a question, and you think:

  > blob of code with no description, code does not help me understand...

  then <kbd>VOTE!</kbd> (down)
- if you read an answer, and you think:

  > good point, that will help the asker.

  then <kbd>VOTE!</kbd> (up)
- if the answer is wrong, or is confusing, and you think:

  > yuck!

  then <kbd>VOTE!</kbd> (down)

Comment: @Jamal I almost flagged that comment,  that song seems kind of annoying, I skipped to the middle and then immediately closed the tab.... sorry...

Comment: Someone please share this response with the main FAQ managers this I think clears up a lot about when to upvote/downvote.