# Let the CR Games begin!

Tags: discussion, fun, user-retention, contest

June is about to end. Summer's here (well, if you're in the northern hemisphere, that is.. otherwise, ... *yay, winter!*), and with it, vacations. We need a new [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge).

Let's play. I mean, let's *find a game to play*.

The game...

- Has to revolve around reviewing code, or posting code for peer review on the main site.
- Has to be open to anyone that wants to enter, at any point in time.
- Shouldn't require any *specific* programming language to be used.

---

> **Suggest *anything*, be creative!**

It doesn't have to be in the shape and form of how we've been using the [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge) tag so far, although it can be. Games could include various types of races - remember, we have the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) that can be used to crunch some numbers!

---

## Your votes have spoken.

Let's go with [@rolfl's idea](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2039/23788), and introduce a [rags-to-riches](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches) tag.

> [image: Cinderella about to go from rags to riches]

> ***Rags to riches*** refers to any situation in which a person rises from poverty to wealth, and in some cases from obscurity to fame - sometimes instantly.
>
> <sub>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rags_to_riches</sub>

---

### Rules

All posts must remain [on-topic](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the main site. **You can't just grab an answer on Stack Overflow and put it up for review!**

Here's what the thing is about.

- **The original code** can be taken from any Stack Exchange site ([Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com), [Programmers](http://www.programmers.stackexchange.com), [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://www.codegolf.stackexchange.com), even [Code Review](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com)!).
- **Your question** must include a link to the Stack Exchange question that contains the original problem.
- **The code in your question** must be *working code*, but grabbing a SO question and *just making it work* is not enough and *should* be downvoted. We want to review *your* code. Don't just make it work, make it *shine*!

Don't forget to tag your posts with [rags-to-riches](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches).

The first to post an entry will be eligible for a [[taxonomist]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) silver badge... if/when the [rags-to-riches](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches) tag gets to 50 posts.

Then you can earn a bronze [rags-to-riches](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches) tag badge with 100 upvotes on at least 20 answers; a silver tag badge with 400 upvotes on at least 80 answers, and a gold tag badge with 1000 upvotes on at least 200 answers... given that many questions :)

Comment: Let the 76th Code Review Games begin! May the odds ever be in your favor.

Comment: So how will a "winner" be decided? Will there be one at all? I think we should set a time limit on it and use SEDE to find out has the best score (whatever that is determined to be) at the end of the time limit.

Comment: @ckuhn203 [tag:community-challenge] has never been about *winning* anything (votes, perhaps), ..I guess the top asker and top answerer in the [tag:rags-to-riches] tag get bragging rights :)

Comment: That's cool. I was just thinking it would be nice to come back and update this post with who those people are after some amount of time.

Comment: @Traven I volunteer for reputation!

Comment: @Corbin I read your comment like 20 times and it doesn't make sense... sorry!

Comment: @Traven It was a Hunger Games themed joke in response to your hunger games themed joke :p. (When she volunteers as tribute.)

Comment: When does the game end? (I.e. can I still post a question with the `rags-to-riches` tag?)

Comment: @11684 that's the best part: the tag has been created, it's here to stay! :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Content posted to Stack Exchange websites is under the Creative Commons license. Specifically, code posted to Stack Overflow and Code Golf are available for use, ..... and abuse!

I suggest we take on the challenge of finding the worst code out there on our sister sites, and making it the best!

If a challenge on Code Golf is interesting, and you think you could do it properly, then do it, and post it for review.

If you find some interesting, but really, really broken code on Stack Overflow, then fix it, and post it for review.

Cleaning up the worst of SE, I suggest the tag: [rags-to-riches](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches) for any such improvements!

Comment: Would that be... all the JAVA questions on SO?

Comment: "If a challenge on Code Golf is interesting, *and you think you could do it properly*" - I presume *properly* stands for "not golfed" ;)

Comment: I'd suggest a [tag:stack-trolling] tag. That's sure to generate tons of views and votes everywhere! (well, ..."code-trolling" *worked* for PCG) And we get to post a comment on the post saying "your post has been trolled [link to CR post]"...

Comment: I should add, that part of the idea would be to hit posts that are high-view posts, and then link back to Code Review.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I think this makes the most sense for Code Golf questions that are not about golfing.

Comment: @Jamal I think you misspelled PHP.

Answer (score 20):

Building on suggestions from @rolfl and @Phrancis… Take any code, maybe from Code Review itself, and implement it from scratch in a language that you are not familiar with. Challenge yourself to learn something new!

Comment: I guess that's my chance to start learning Java...

Comment: Just don't learn JAVA @Jamal.

Comment: This could be a good chance for me to really get started in Ruby and extend my knowledge in the languages I already know.

Comment: Tag: [tag:translated] perhaps?  This might be useful for questions unrelated to this challenge as well.  For example, where I work (not that I post work code, but as example), I'm tasked with creating a mobile app with some of the functionality of an existing desktop app.  The mobile app is being written in Objective-C and the desktop is in VB.Net.  I'm no VB.Net expert, so when I translate, I'd want to make sure I maintain all the functionality of the old code.  We could have questions with original code and translated code, etc.

Comment: So i should learn APL? :P

Comment: @SamDenton Only if you can convince someone to review it!

Comment: I'm sure somone out there can understand it?!

Answer (score 10):

Many of the code review answers address the same things for the same languages.  Write a program to automatically create a plausible CR answer for one or more programming languages so that less experienced programmers can run it on their own code offline.

Comment: Rewrite JSHint.com ?

Comment: There are many existing static code analysis tools for many different languages.  Writing one is an interesting exercise closely akin to writing a compiler front-end.  Being able to handle multiple languages would be an interesting twist on the usual design of such tools.

Comment: I am afraid this would be too simple. If the question is tagged 'Java', it should just say 'You should do this in C++, it is faster'. If the question is not tagged Java, the system should say 'You should write this in Java, which is cross-platform high-performing, and has a more efficient development paradigm'.

Comment: @rolfl: Ah, but that's why I specifically specified "a *plausible* CR answer."

Answer (score 8):

Maybe we can find one of the most vague questions on SO, and write the best potential code in any language that would accomplish that purpose. That may show CR's expertise in a multitude of ways of accomplishing a goal with best practices, etc. in mind? Kind of random but curious what you all think.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on the ideas of others... Write a piece of code in a language that you don't know, which writes code into a language which you also do not know yet, all taken from an existing code review question, also coded in a language you do not know.

Do the ultimate challenge.

Comment: Not sure I like this. Code-generating-code is never nice, and neat. It is hard to understand, and does not make for easy-to-review systems because the reviewer needs to be expert in both of the languages.