# Memes related to The Mission

Tags: discussion

A [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18766505#18766505) was originated in chat about CR memes, here are the most relevant parts:

> 200_success: 
> Speaking from my own opinion, rather than as a moderator, I find several of the listed memes to be problematic. In particular:
>
> - [Ammo](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1515/9357), [napalm](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1512/9357), and [ho-ho-ho-napalm](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2262/9357). We fought a great battle. We won. A permanent state of war is unhealthy. It would be a nice graduation celebration to declare **Mission Accomplished**, I think.
>
> Having stated that, I don't think I should censor any of those posts. I'm also not sure whether they should be marked "of historical interest" or just deleted. I'll leave it up to the individuals involved to decide on the appropriate action.

So, I decided to post it on Meta to see what others think. Should we:

1. Leave them be;
2. <strike>Mark them</strike> Comment/Edit them as "of historical interest"/"obsolete"; or,
3. Delete them.

Also, if the CR community wanted to do (2) "of historical interest", what is the process to do that?

Comment: To clarify: there is currently no Stack Exchange feature to annotate that an answer is no longer valid. By marking, I meant commenting and/or editing.

Comment: I have put in a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244134/148099) for marking posts as obsolete.

Comment: OK meanwhile I have reworded Point (2) in my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Going through this from bottom up:

### Deleting:

I am strongly opposed to deleting these memes, after all "We fought a great battle." Let the memes bear testimony of our battle. Deletion limits the knowledge of these memes to us veterans. It creates a subcommunity inside our now expanding community.

We shouldn't reclude ourselves into the 2nd monitor as the battle hardened veterans we are. The "new recruits" shall know of our glory, so they can understand better why we are who we are.

### Historical Significance:

If memory serves right, there is no possible way to mark single answers as "of historical significance". Either we lock down and freeze the whole post or we don't. As new memes may emerge any-time, I'd prefer to leave this open for modification. Maybe the question needs a little rephrasing then and now and a new answer here and there.

This one's out too...

### Leave them be:

How much I'd like to do that, there's a problem with this.. We should let peace come into our lives. There is no need for Zombies, napalm strikes or Santa dropping carpet bombs.

The memes have lived their life to the fullest. I'd say let them rest.

### The solution:

I'd say we add a retirement notice to the veteran memes. Something along the lines of:

> This meme has been retired by [community decision]({meta-link}) on {date here}. It is thus considered a veteran meme. Usages may still occur, but the meme has largely vanished from our site.

Comment: I like this. Kind of a "this meme is of historical importance" notice without actually locking the post.

Comment: Technical observation: Individual answers can be locked. Unfortunately, the only two lock reasons available are: "Content Dispute", and "Off-topic Comments". The full text for 'Content Dispute' is: *This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta.*

Comment: I have commented in your remark into the 3 memes in the question. Thanks for the agreeable suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

I agree with 200: war is over, we won. I think deleting these posts would be wrong though, and leaving them untouched makes us look like we're still fighting an army of zombies (eh, that's *so 2013*!).

I think it would be reasonable to lock them and preserve history. We never know, maybe there's an unforeseen zombie uprising brewing...

Comment: There's a significant problem with locking.. we'd lock down the whole meme-post..

Comment: @Vogel612 good point. I like your answer anyway :)

Comment: Technical observation: Individual answers can be locked. Unfortunately, the only two lock reasons available are: "Content Dispute", and "Off-topic Comments". The full text for 'Content Dispute' is: *This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta.*

Answer (score 0):

## Create a new Meme Post for a new Era!

Lock the Pre-Graduation post and create a new post for new memes

(***link back to the veteran memes***)

---

## Split the Post into 2 posts

One for Veteran Memes and one for not Veteran Memes, then lock the historical Veteran Meme Post

Comment: this suggestion somewhat suffers from the same problem as deleting the veteran memes, just in a much less extreme way. Also not all memes listed in that post are veteran memes. Also splitting the post probably makes it lose votes. If memory serves right, there is no way of splitting a Q&A pair, only merging is possible...