# I don't think this tag [functions] quite well

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The tag [functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) doesn't seem very useful.  The tag wiki only states the definition and the questions just... contain functions.  In terms of reviewing, there aren't really any differences between questions with just functions or with all the implemented code.  Users may just end up using the tag if their question contains one or more functions.  At the worst, it could be used just because the code already "functions" properly.

I don't think synonymization would work, so burnination (or not) may be the only options.

[image]

Comment: +1 for use of title :-)

Comment: +1 for punz :D (incidentally, I almost edited it to say `[function]s` because I misread the tag)

Comment: Useless tag, make it burn.

Comment: Where are the +1s on the three tag-puns I created today/yesterday?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree.  [functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) is not a useful tag for describing the content in a post, and not all languages call their functions "functions", including C# and Java, which calls their functions "methods" instead.

Comment: a Method can be described as a function. but you are completely right. function isn't a good tag

Comment: A method is a special type of function.  All methods are functions.  Not all functions are methods.  In Objective-C, we can even extrapolate a C-style function implementation of *any* method call.

Comment: Well, nobody ever calls a C# method a function, as far as I know.  Thanks for the correction, @nhgrif.  Is this more correct?

Comment: @Hosch250 Except that C# does have anonymous functions. And it also has anonymous methods, which are a kind of anonymous functions (the other kind is lambda expressions). (Yes, this part of nomenclature is a mess in C#.)

Answer (score 2):

When I first saw this, I thought

> Why are we burning a tag for functional programming, we have [oop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oop), why not this?

Then I looked at the questions tagged with [functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) and how it's being used. I can't see how it's adding any value. For a moment I thought that perhaps some of these should be tagged with [single-responsibility-principle](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-responsibility-principle), but that's pretty meta and it's possible that we already burnt that one.

TL;DR:

[image: Kill it with fire.]