# Dispose of [idisposable]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There are 3 questions tagged [idisposable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idisposable), one closed as off-topic, the other two featuring an `IDisposable` implementation.

I don't think we need a tag for any specific interface of the .NET framework - that includes [ienumerable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ienumerable), which is the only other tag I've found for a .NET interface.

These interfaces are part of a framework; I believe tagging with [.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net) would be much more relevant, especially since we're talking, with the two tags combined, about merely 20 questions, vs. 520 for the framework tag.

My reasoning is that the [.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag is most relevant when a question is about specifics of the framework, and both `IEnumerable` and `IDisposable` perfectly fit in there.

The opposite direction is annoying IMO: we could very well end up with [iserializable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iserializable) and [iformatprovider](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iformatprovider) and whatnot - I think posts about the .NET framework should be tagged with [.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net), and that we don't really need a tag for specific interfaces. The mechanics of `IDisposable` are intrinsic to those of the framework itself, as are those of `IEnumerable`.

I think these interface tags need to burn, and be replaced with [.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net).

Comment: Given that I don't get any [ns...] tags, I emphatically agree.

Comment: If you're also for burninating [tag:ienumerable], then you can probably revise this question as such.  It doesn't look like there are any differences in terms of worth.

Comment: @Jamal I'll make a separate post for `IEnumerable`, linking to this one.

Comment: Related: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5654/there-are-ienumerable-reasons-to-burn-this-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [idisposable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idisposable) was unnecessary on [Would you utilise "Using" on a member which is going to be added to a list?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71358/would-you-utilise-using-on-a-member-which-is-going-to-be-added-to-a-list) so I removed it (the closed question).

The question [Async distributed locking with StackExchange.Redis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82944/async-distributed-locking-with-stackexchange-redis) is also a poor question, and I am considering closing it. The question is basically: "I am using iDisposable on an async system, but it should only be used on a sync system, can I still use it?" Despite the upvotes, it's not really a good code review question... well, the code is OK, but the question is better on SO.... I have closed the question, and changed the tag to [.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net)

The third question is [WinSCP IDisposable Wrapper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75131/winscp-idisposable-wrapper) and the need to put the iDisposable in the title indicates the lack of need for it in the tags. I have changed that to [.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net).

The tag is now gone.

Comment: What of IEnumerable?

Comment: iEnumerable will probably take more time, and won't be a quick fix. Thoughts? If you want to go through them by hand then that's an option, @Mat'sMug

Answer (score 3):

[memory-management](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory-management) would be a suitable and language agnostic replacement for [idisposable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idisposable).

From the memory management wiki (emphasis mine):

> Memory management is the act of managing computer memory. The essential requirement of memory management is to provide ways to dynamically allocate portions of memory to programs at their request, and **freeing it for reuse when no longer needed.**

From the [MSDN page for IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Provides a mechanism for releasing unmanaged resources.

Sounds like memory management to me. If this tag pops back up, they should become synonyms.

Comment: I actually did the same for one question and the OP told me it was incorrect.  I don't recall the exact question, though.

Comment: That's a shame @Jamal. I would have liked to have seen the context and OP's reasoning.

Comment: Maybe I can try to dig it out by searching.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/67838/revisions

Comment: Hmm... I can't imagine why he didn't think it was relevant... He was actually forcing [tag:garbage-collection] in that code, which was already made a synonym of [tag:memory-management]. Odd.