# There are [ienumerable] reasons to burn this tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Noting that [we have disposed of](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5595/36366) [idisposable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idisposable) and have decided as a community that [we don't need tags this specific to languages](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5595/dispose-of-idisposable#comment12771_5595), we still have [ienumerable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ienumerable) hanging about which needs to be enumerated out of existence.

Requesting burnination.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend that we synonymize [ienumerable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ienumerable) into [iterator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iterator).

From the [iterator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iterator) tag wiki:

> An iterator is an object-oriented programming pattern which for the most part functions similarly to a pointer to an object inside a collection with the added ability to traverse through the collection in a defined manner, agnostic of the actual implementation or even object addresses in physical memory. Iterators may be further limited in particular traversal directions.

I'll leave it to the .NET experts to comment or up/down vote on whether or not this is an acceptable synonym for [ienumerable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ienumerable).

Comment: `IEnumerable` merely exposes a `GetEnumerator` method which returns an `IEnumerator` - I can see `IEnumerable` (the tag) coming back into existence regularly, but making it a synonym of the pattern it's implementing sounds pretty reasonable.

Comment: [Synonym suggested](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/iterator/synonyms); go ahead and vote for it.