# action = ([ternary-operator] == bad_tag ? "burninate" : "keep")

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Currently, there's 17 tagged questions for this tag, either being superfluous (*use every tag I can*) kinda questions, or very complex ternaries replaced a potentially large `if-else` statement, like [Forming a dictionary where all values are only conditionally set](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88369/forming-a-dictionary-where-all-values-are-only-conditionally-set)

Should [ternary-operator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ternary-operator) be burninated or as @Jamal pointed out in the comments, or synonymise with [conditions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditions)?

Comment: Noooooo *(yes)*

Comment: What about synonymization with [tag:conditions]?

Comment: This title should be `[ternary-operator].bad_tag()`, not `==`. `==` makes no sense here.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes `bad_tag` is a constant, whereas `[ternary-operator]` doesn't have a bad tag method

Comment: Yeah, but `==` suggests that there's only one tag that's `bad_tag`. Maybe `bad_tags.include([ternary-operator])`?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, not necessarily. `bad_tag` as a constant can be compared to any other tag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this should be synonymized with [conditions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditions) instead of burninating it altogether.  This does still involve conditionals, the difference being is that this is about the operator.  A few questions are also already tagged with [conditions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditions).

I've suggested the synonymization [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/conditions/synonyms).