# if ( [conditions].isGoodTag() ) { return "keep" } else { return "burninate" }

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There are currently [246 questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditions?sort=newest&pageSize=50) tagged with [conditions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditions). It also has 2 synonyms, [conditionals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditionals) and [ternary-operator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ternary-operator)

Reference: [action = ([ternary-operator] == bad_tag ? “burninate” : “keep”)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5630/action-ternary-operator-bad-tag-burninate-keep/5631#5631)

The tag may be too meta or too general to provide useful information about a post.

1. Practically all code ever written uses conditions in one form or another. All loops also have conditions. As such, we could tag practically every question with [conditions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditions), which then makes the tag useless.
2. Looking through the questions tagged with it, I could not find any particularly distinguishing feature to justify the use of that tag. I tried to find a question that was "about conditions" rather than just "uses conditions" but did not find such a question.

At the moment the tag only has 4 followers. I personally cannot think of any particularly good reason to keep that tag around, though if someone can make a case for it, by all means please do so!

Comment: Eww, what an anti-pattern! Try `return  [conditions].isGoodTag() ? "keep" : "burninate"`, or even better `return [true: "keep", false: "burninate"][[conditions].isGoodTag()]` (branches and jumps are slow, you know)

Comment: @cat That could be golfier. `return["burninate","keep"][[conditions].isGoodTag()]` Code-golf FTW!

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Golfiness at the expense of readability D: This is CR, not PPCG!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with Trogdor's assistance, [conditions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditions) stayed alive due to its Horcrux: the synonymized [ternary-operator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ternary-operator) still tagged with some questions.  With no <s>soul pieces</s> questions remaining, [conditions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditions) will finally part (along with [ternary-operator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ternary-operator)).

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Really, I think that the tag is really broad.

We have enough tags that we don't need one for Conditions.

(almost)All code has conditions in it for one thing or another.  I really don't think that adding the [conditions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditions) to any question adds any quality to the question.

## Burn it, Burn it with Fire!