# Best of Code Review 2016

Tags: discussion, fun, best-of

As 2016 comes to an end, let's kick off Best of Code Review 2016!

All Code Review users will be invited to nominate (link to) the best questions and answers from this year, and showcase them as examples of what great CR questions and answers should look like.  Prizes in the form of bounties will be awarded wherever feasible.

---

### Conclusion

The winners of Best of Code Review 2016 are:

- **Best Newcomer (question)**

  [Disproving Euler proposition by brute force in C](/a/7139/9357) by @Aidenhjj
- **Best Newcomer (answer)**

  [Implementing realloc in C](/a/7155/9357) by @CodyGray
- **Best Title**

  [The right way to hang a man](/a/7150/9357) by @N3buchadnezzar
- **Diplomat**

  [Google Foobar Challenge: Lucky Triples](/a/7159/9357) by @GarethRees
- **Exterminator**

  [CultureInfo with fallback routing to another language](/a/7142/9357) by @EBrown
- **Night and Day**

  [Charmander Brainfuck interpreter in Haskell](/a/7170/9357), question by @IgnisIncendio and answer by @Zeta

Thanks to the Code Review members who are donating their points as bounty prizes to the winners!

Comment: When is the closing date for voting?  It would be good to know what day to check the question for late nominations and cast final votes.

Comment: @forsvarir Last year it ran for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 24):

**[Best Newcomer (Answer) category](/q/7128):** Best answer by a user who had not posted an answer before 2016.

Comment: [**Rookie of the Year**](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10964/63903) Like on PPCG.

Answer (score 20):

**[Diplomat](/q/7130):** Tough advice in an answer, delivered in the most tactful manner.

Answer (score 19):

**[Best Newcomer (Question) category](/q/7129):** Best question by a user who had not posted a question before 2016.

Answer (score 15):

**[Best Title category](/q/7131):** The question with the best title. (If the title was later added by someone else, be sure to credit the user who edited the title.)

Answer (score 12):

**[Night and Day](/q/7133):** The most dramatic improvement (nominate both the question with the most hopeless code and the answer that cleans it up the best).

Answer (score 11):

**[Exterminator](/q/7132):** Answer that points out the most interesting obscure bug in the original code.

Answer (score 8):

**Jamalizer* Award category**, for question edits that turned bad questions into good ones.

*[see *Jamalized*](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1675/23788)

Comment: Would it be possible to make a SEDE query to scan for this? Something like: Question has low score, question is edited, question gets much higher score.

Comment: @SimonForsberg No, I'm afraid we'd have to do this from memory. Or judge based on the edit history, not on the vote count.

Comment: I like this one, I think we should make a trophy...

Answer (score 4):

**Rags to Riches category:** The [rags-to-riches](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rags-to-riches) question that took the worst original code and made it shine like a polished gem.

Comment: This is very similar to Night and Day.  Especially as the new question typically starts as an answer to the first question.