# Missing questions and answers in Best of Code Review 2016 query results

Tags: discussion, best-of

I noticed that some of my questions and answers from 2016 failed to appear in the query results for [Best of Code Review 2016](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7102/best-of-code-review-2016-now-accepting-nominations). For example, [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/610400/best-of-code-review-2016-best-newcomer-question-category) returned only one of my questions, while I asked four questions in 2016. I also saw that an answer was missing in the query for Best Newcomer (answer) category.

At first I thought that it was because these posts were made in December, but then I saw that other December posts were included in the results.

It is not that I expect to win anything here, but I don't understand why these posts are not showing in the query results. Maybe others also have posts that are not appearing in the queries. This seems a little unfair, since the nomination page states that this query "will show all potential candidates."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like those queries are set up to only display the *first* post from each user who hadn't posted before 2016, rather than all posts in 2016 of each user who hadn't posted before 2016.

[Best Newcomer Question](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/611421/best-of-code-review-best-newcomer-question-category?Year=2016)

That should be a fixed version.

I have also updated the linked query in that Meta question and the 'Best of ... Answer' question as well.

[Best Newcomer Answer](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/611431/best-of-code-review-best-newcomer-answer-category)

Thanks for pointing this out! :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing this. It looks like the queries are working now! :)

Comment: @DavidBowling No problem. It was just a misunderstanding from the person who wrote the original (awesome) queries. :)